# Why do I keep getting a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on a weak Ai similar to Siri and Cortana however i have noticed i keep receiving a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'", along side this instead of my code picking up my query, it always prints out 'Sorry i did not catch that'.Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

Errors :

```
if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

code:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import pythoncom

print("Initializing Karren")

MASTER = "Bob"

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

    if hour>=0 and hour <12:
        speak("Good Morning" + MASTER)

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon" + MASTER)
    else:
        speak("Good Evening" + MASTER)


   # speak("I am Karren. How may I assist you?") # deliberately on not included for now

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try :
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, Language = 'en-uk')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
        query = None
    return query 

speak("Initializing Karren...")
wishMe()
query = takeCommand()


if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
    speak("Searching wikipedia")
    query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
    speak(results)
```

Comment: You may need to indent your try statement so it falls under the with sr.Microphone() as source... block of code.

Comment: In your `takeCommand` function, it's possible that it will return `query = None` if the recognition fails. You can set it to return empty string if you don't want this error from `.lower()`.

Comment: You set ``query = None`` in ``takeCommand``. This path should have printed additional error information to you. Note that it doesn't make sense to "handle" an exception by corrupting your program - if ``query`` cannot be meaningfully set when an exception is encountered, don't suppress the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `takeCommand` is returning `None`.  `None` doesn't have a `lower` method, so you're getting this error.

One thing you can do is log more information about the exception being thrown in `takeCommand` that is causing it to enter the `except` block, or just remove the `try` block so the exception stops the program, then read the traceback.

Comment: im sorry im fairly new to python,could you explain this in further detail please.

Comment: When you do `query = takeCommand()` where `takeCommand` returns `None`, then `query.lower()`, it's the same as doing `None.lower()`.  Since `None` doesn't have a `lower` method, this fails. The second part of my answer addresses how to fix your actual problem, which is that `r.recognize_google` is failing.  The easiest way to do this is to remove all of your error handling code so that your can see the exception it is raising.  Hopefully, that exception will contain some information that allows you to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
def takeCommand():
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try :
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, Language = 'en-uk')
    print(f"User said: {query}\n")

except Exception as e:
    print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
    query = "None" # or whatever str
return query
```

Tried this out myself. In Takecommand() function, where query = none, replace none with a string. Reason being when you encounter the error, Nonetype has no attribute to lower, query = none and since it isn't a str or whatever, lower() can't transform it. As mentioned above this is one way to solve this error without encountering any more. Tested response.

Otherwsie remove the query = none